# CSS set two column static

Tags: html, css

> Hello, I need help at styling the table. I want the update/delete
>   button and its table cell to be static and hope anyone out there can
>   help. My issue is when i stretch the table, or expand to fill in the
>   details in other rows, the buttons and its column will expand and
>   shrink. How do I make both buttons not expand and the the two column
>   cells to be static/fixed.
>
> So far I've tried position: absolute/fixed/auto and display:
>   inline-block/auto.

My CSS here

```
.button td {

    white-space: nowrap;
    position: absolute;   /*to fixed the button location*/ 

    }

.center {
    display: table-cell;
text-align: center;
}
```

[CODE SAMPLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/8p426fog/202/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

two things:

- you are applying `.button td` but your `.button` is already a `td` so it should it only be applied `.button`
- the other when you are applying `position:absolute` to a child element, is always better to apply `position:relative` to its parent

> **absolute**
>
> Do not leave space for the element. Instead, position it at a specified position relative to its closest positioned ancestor or to
>   the containing block. Absolutely positioned boxes can have margins,
>   they do not collapse with any other margins.

More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

So here is a snippet:

```css
.button {
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  /*to fixed the button location*/
}
.center {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
}
table.table {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: small;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  table-layout: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
table.table td {
  padding: 5px;
  border: solid 1px #7f7f7f;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 125px;
  height: 25px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 2px;
  position: relative;
}
table.table th {
  border: 1px solid #7f7f7f;
  padding: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 125px;
  height: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #5C82FF;
  color: white;
}
table.table th a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding-right: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <table id="datatable" class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="display: none;">ID</th>
        <th>Name<i style="color: red">*</i>

        </th>
        <th>Contact<i style="color: red">*</i>

        </th>
        <th>Contact 2</th>
        <th>Fax</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Location<i style="color: red">*</i>

        </th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <form:input path="name" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <form:input path="contact" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <form:input path="contact2" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <form:input path="contactfax" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <form:input path="fax" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <form:input path="location" />
        </td>
        <div class="center">
          <td class="button">
            <input type="submit" value="Update" style=" margin: 0 auto;" />
          </td>
        </div>
        <div class="center">
          <td class="button">
            <input type="submit" value="Delete" style=" margin: 0 auto;" />
          </td>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the valuable info. I'll study the code and apply to mine to make the necessary changes.Thanks again, have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

My answer [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AleshaOleg/Lpda2y4z/).

Just set a min-width to your columns.

HTML

```
<table id="datatable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th style="display: none;">ID</th>
        <th>Name<i style="color: red">*</i></th>
        <th>Contact<i style="color: red">*</i></th>
        <th>Contact 2</th>
        <th>Fax</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Location<i style="color: red">*</i></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><form:input path="name"/></td>          
        <td><form:input path="contact"/></td>
        <td><form:input path="contact2"/></td>
        <td><form:input path="contactfax"/></td>
        <td><form:input path="fax"/></td>                           
        <td><form:input path="location" /></td>
        <td class="button">
            <input  type="submit" value="Update" style=" margin: 0 auto;"/>
        </td>
        <td class="button">
            <input type="submit" value="Delete"  style=" margin: 0 auto;"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

CSS

```
table { 
    font-family:arial; 
    font-size:small; 
    word-wrap: break-word;
    table-layout: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

table th { 
    border: 1px solid #7f7f7f; 
    padding: 5px; 
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 125px;
    height: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #5C82FF;
    color: white;
}

table th a { 
    text-decoration: none; 
    text-align: center; 
    padding-right: 20px; 
    font-weight:bold; 
    white-space:nowrap; 
}

table td { 
    padding: 5px; 
    border: solid 1px #7f7f7f; 
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 125px;
    height: 25px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 2px;
}

.button {
    white-space: nowrap;
    min-width: 100px;
}

.center {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you very much for taking the time and effort to reply. I'll definitely study the code and apply to mine to make the necessary changes. Thanks again, have a nice day!